# how conversion select into query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I need to convert this Select from `sql server` to `Access`

```
select ep.SWProduct_ID, ep.NormalizedName, e.Product, e.CreatedDate, MAX(m3.MappedDate)
from V_EOLProducts_ToMap ep 
inner join V_eol e on ep.Product = e.Product
inner join T_ProductEOL_Mapping m3 on m3.SwProduct_ID=e.SwProduct_ID 
where e.CreatedDate >'2018-07-05' 
and not exists (select * from T_ProductEOL_Mapping m where m.eol_id=e.eol_id)
and exists (select * from T_ProductEOL_Mapping m2 where m2.SwProduct_ID=e.SwProduct_ID)
AND e.CreatedDate > m3.MappedDate
group by ep.SWProduct_ID, ep.NormalizedName, e.Product, e.CreatedDate
order by SwProduct_ID
```

I have tried the query below and i also need to change the value `#01/07/2018#` into a variable

```
select ep.SWProduct_ID, ep.NormalizedName, e.Product, e.CreatedDate, MAX(m3.MappedDate)

from (dbo_V_EOLProducts_ToMap ep 
inner join dbo_V_eol e on ep.Product = e.Product)
inner join dbo_T_ProductEOL_Mapping m3 on m3.SwProduct_ID=e.SwProduct_ID 

where e.CreatedDate >#01/07/2018#
and not exists (select * from dbo_T_ProductEOL_Mapping m where m.eol_id=e.eol_id)
and exists (select * from dbo_T_ProductEOL_Mapping m2 where m2.SwProduct_ID=e.SwProduct_ID)
AND e.CreatedDate > m3.MappedDate

group by ep.SWProduct_ID, ep.NormalizedName, e.Product, e.CreatedDate

order by ep.SwProduct_ID
```

EDIT
From the comments it seems he is getting this error

[image]

Comment: Do you mean how to convert it to T-SQL?

Comment: no from SQL to Access SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

access has a very weird join style, you need lots of brackets.
if I remember correct this should get your join valid for access

```
from ((dbo_V_EOLProducts_ToMap ep 
  inner join dbo_V_eol e on ep.Product = e.Product)
  inner join dbo_T_ProductEOL_Mapping m3 on m3.SwProduct_ID = e.SwProduct_ID)
```

Comment: still i have error 
https://software-solutions-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/type-mismatch1.png

Comment: Well why dont you edit your question and put this error there so everyone can see it. You might get more and better answers then

Comment: My guess is that the date is in the wrong format in the where clause, but I have no idea what format access wants for date values